# Continious operation using services

Tags: service, intentservice

I would like to read data from a server and write it to file every 5 minutes.
In case there is a network problem I need to report it to the `MainActivity`.
What is the best way to do it? Can I use IntentService?
Is it a good idea to put a `while()` loop inside `onStart()` method?